# UIView frame auto reset

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3, frame

I have this simple code, initializing an `UILabel`

At first print, frame width/height are correct, but at second, all values of frame are 0.

```
let messageBoxFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: BAND_HEIGHT)
print(messageBoxFrame)
let messageBox = UILabel(frame: messageBoxFrame)
messageBox.textAlignment = .center
messageBox.textColor = UIColor.white
messageBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
messageBox.sizeToFit()
print(messageBox.frame)
```

Comment: If you're using auto layout but don't want to set constraints, add this:
`messageBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messageBox.sizeToFit()` this line of code is adjusting your `UILabel` frame

As per this [sizeToFit()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622630-sizetofit)

> Call this method when you want to resize the current view so that it
>   uses the most appropriate amount of space. Specific UIKit views resize
>   themselves according to their own internal needs. In some cases, if a
>   view does not have a superview, it may size itself to the screen
>   bounds. Thus, if you want a given view to size itself to its parent
>   view, you should add it to the parent view before calling this method.

Comment: Thank's, it's work now. I was thinking i can use `sizeToFit` for center text in Label